# How to Post and Get Images from Google's MyBusiness API

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I have access into all 8 of Google's MybusinessbusinessV1 API's.

I filled the form and they gave me enough quota.

In my app I already connected and can get information from the accounts and locations.

However, I can't find how to get images/videos and upload images/videos through the API

From what I read, the old v4.9 API had those options:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media?hl=en&authuser=0

But they are obsolete now and I can't connect to it

I even tried using my authenticated v1 client to access that API  (using their doc: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media/list )

```
Sending HTTP GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'accountnumber'/locations/'locationsnumber'/media
403
Caught error PERMISSION_DENIED: Google My Business API has not been used in project "project's number" before or it is disabled. 
Enable it by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=project's number" then retry. 
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Of course, that link doesn't work anymore.

I can't find any information on MybusinessbusinessV1 APIs to work with media, but I know there are services out there that can do it, do you have any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v4 methods for media are not deprecated yet.

The old API has a separate quota, use the same form you already used to also request quota for the old API.